# hide parameters from URL from address bar after accessing parameters in reactjs Routes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a url like this `"http://localhost:3000/MockApi/getDetails/A1B@$CZSK_2"`

I want to hide `"A1B@$CZSK_2"` part from the URL.

When above URL clicked it will be go to this component

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams , } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>(null);
  const { key } = useParams();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:8080/MockApi/getDetails/${key}`;
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        // Handle the API response data
        setData(data);
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      });
  }, [key]);

  return (
    <div className="container col-12 col-md-3 mt-5 ">
      <div>
        <div className="row justify-content-center border border-secondary p-3 rounded text-center shadow">
          <div className="col-md-7">
            <h2 className="text-center">ABC Company</h2>
            <form className="mt-3 text-center">
              <div className='container'>
                {data && <h4 className="text-center pt-5">MSISDN: {data.msisdn}</h4>}
                {data && <h4 className="text-center pt-5">ServerRef: {data.severRef}</h4>}   
              </div>
  
              <div className="mb-3 pt-5 text-center">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="OTP"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="OTP"
                />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary w-100">
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
  
export default App;
```

when this component display in the browser I need to hide `"A1B@$CZSK_2"` part from URL in the address bar and need to stay in the same page which is the App component only need to hide the url key (`"A1B@$CZSK_2"`)

This is how routes look like:

```
import './App.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Routes, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './home';

function MainApp() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Router basename='/api' location={"/"} navigator={}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/MockApi/getDetails/:key" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainApp;
```

I used `MemoryRouter`, `useNavigate`, and `useHistroy`, none worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide parameters from Route after accessing parameters in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925804/how-to-hide-parameters-from-route-after-accessing-parameters-in-reactjs)

Comment: no it does not I already try it

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here would be to make the `key` segment optional (*using the `"?"` on the segment*), and in the routed component to redirect to `"/MockApi/getDetails"` as soon as the `key` parameter has been consumed.

Example:

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './home';

function MainApp() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router basename='/api'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/MockApi/getDetails/:key?" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainApp;
```

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { key } = useParams();

  const [data, setData] = useState<any>(null);  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (key) {
      navigate("/MockApi/getDetails", { replace: true });

      const apiUrl = `http://localhost:8080/MockApi/getDetails/${key}`;
      fetch(apiUrl)
        .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          // Handle the API response data
          setData(data);
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        });
    }
  }, [key]);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
  
export default App;
```